# Check timestamp column if it is a multiple of 5 minutes, and remove the beginning and end so that it starts/ ends with 5-mins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 1-min time series data

```
df
timestamp          col
2020-10-10 0:02    10
2020-10-10 0:03    20
2020-10-10 0:04    12
2020-10-10 0:05    30
....
```

I want to make sure that it starts with a multiple of 5. So here, I want to remove the rows until 0:05 because it starts with a 2-minute and the closest multiple of 5 is that row. I have bunch of files in a folder, so please suggest a scalable answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't modulo `%` help you out in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert as `DatetimeIndex` then extract minutes. Finally apply the modulo 5, check the remainder and get the first True index:

```
start_idx = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.minute.mod(5).eq(0).idxmax()
```

Output:

```
>>> start_idx
3

>>> df.loc[start_idx:]
         timestamp  col
3  2020-10-10 0:05   30
```

Comment: Hi @prof32. Does my answer or other solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import random

base = pd.Timestamp.today()
timestamp_list = [base + dt.timedelta(minutes=x) for x in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [i for i in timestamp_list], 'col1': [random.randrange(1, 11) for i in range(10)]})
df = df.loc[(df['timestamp'].dt.minute % 5== 0).idxmax() :]
print (df)
```

### OUTPUT

```
0 2023-03-10 18:10:02.938585     4
1 2023-03-10 18:11:02.938585     4
2 2023-03-10 18:12:02.938585     4
3 2023-03-10 18:13:02.938585     9
4 2023-03-10 18:14:02.938585     2
5 2023-03-10 18:15:02.938585     9
6 2023-03-10 18:16:02.938585     9
7 2023-03-10 18:17:02.938585     9
8 2023-03-10 18:18:02.938585     9
9 2023-03-10 18:19:02.938585     9
```